# How can I organize "IF ELSE" in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I organize "IF ELSE" in Selenium IDE WITHOUT use extensions?

Comment: What do you mean by "organize"? Selenium IDE doesn't support `if` statements without using extensions or plugins.

Comment: This is impossible for common cases, but can be done in special situations

Comment: here is my task, but right-done in SEL. RC : if 
  (selenium.getSelectedLabel("xpath=//select[@name='cnt']")=="[choose]" == true) {
   System.out.println("[Выбрать]");
   verifyFalse(selenium.isEditable("xpath=//select[@name='city']"));
   verifyFalse(selenium.isEditable("xpath=//select[@name='reg']"));
   
   } else if
   (selenium.getSelectedLabel("xpath=//select[@name='cnt']")=="[choose]" == false) {
    System.out.println("[CHOOSE] ERROR!");
       };

Comment: @user1211063 just do `assertSelectedLabel` and then two `assertNotEditable`. But what do you have against extensions?

Comment: Sometimes, I can't to use extensions. Thanks to all, I already know, how can I do it (by javascript). Something like this: "runScript | javascript{alert('Thanks... I feel much better now!');} "

Answer (score 4):

Just to conclude it for future readers:

1. The "right" and most complete way is to download a `Flow Control` plugin for Selenium IDE from the [official page](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) (aaaall the way down).

   The most useful link I found is this one, because it has a complete example in it: http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/if-else-statement-td4370.html

   Anyway, there's also a [documentation](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/flowControl) and [author's blogpost](http://51elliot.blogspot.cz/2008/02/selenium-ide-goto.html) explaining something more.
2. Without any Selenium IDE plugins (what a silly demand - Selenium IDE *itself* is a plugin!), there's nothing you can do besides writing the whole command in JavaScript. For this, the following functions may come in handy: [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById), [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName), [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) and [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate).

Answer (score 1):

Use Gotoif condition.

Here is an example for Gotoif condition:

```
 <tr>
        <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${test}</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['test']=false</td>
    <td>labltest</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>labltest</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>

 </tbody></table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To use If..Else in selenium IDE, first add the plugin "SelBlock"/ link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/versions/. After that only you can able to use If..Else in your test case.
Example:

```
<head>
<body>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=signin</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${test}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>if</td>
    <td>${test}==true</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=signin</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>else</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Logout')])[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endIf</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</body>
```