# Selenium IDE and handling conditional JavaScript pop up

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to handle a JavaScript pop up in Selenium IDE. My Selenium IDE code is as below:

```
click   id=chk_MITS64906_ZTDLA15RT

click   id=AddDispute

select  id=cmbIssueCategory   label=Billing Support Documents Required

select  id=cmbIssue     label=Customer needs copy of Customer invoice

click   link=Submit

assertAlert     There is Open dispute on following InvoiceNumber=ZTDLA15RT for Category=Billing Support Documents Required
```

assertalert is the pop up I want to handle. It depends on situation say if there is a dispute alert will come else wont.

If I keep the assertAlert in case of no dispute it will fail as alert will not be present.
So how can I handle it in both conditions.

Thanks,
Nits

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium IDE, it is not possible to handle the Conditional statements without using the plug-in.

For your case you can go for the `Flow Control` plug-in.
[Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498966/how-can-i-organize-if-else-selenium-ide) it will help you.

Comment: thanks...i got it using eclipse                          if(selenium.isAlertPresent())
  {
   assertEquals("There is Open dispute on following InvoiceNumber=ZTDLA15RT for Category=Rating Error", selenium.getAlert());
  }
  else
  {
   verifyFalse(selenium.isAlertPresent());
  }
  
  }

Comment: Please be more clear while asking question. You asked a question as i want solution in SIDE and we provide the solution. Now you moved to RC. That's fine but don't make us fools.