# Selenium IDE checkbox checked identification

Tags: selenium, checkbox, ide, checked

I am learning how to use Selenium IDE and it's going pretty well I think, but now I can't seems to find how I can check the checkbox on that Page.

https://www.otelo.de/warenkorb.html?id=-1

I can't seem to find out how to see if the checkbox is checked

The only thing selenium ide is showing me is `id=mnp` if I try to record it

Can you please help me and tell me what am I doing wrong?

thx you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [SelBlocks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/) Plugin for If-Else You can use `storeChecked` to store the state of checkbox

> **storeChecked**(locator, variableName)
>   Generated from isChecked(locator)
>       Arguments:
>
> ```
>    locator - an element locator pointing to a checkbox or radio button
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
>       true if the checkbox is checked, false otherwise
> ```
>
> Gets whether a toggle-button (checkbox/radio) is checked. Fails if the specified element doesn't exist or isn't a toggle-button.

[image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <title>IfElse</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">IfElse</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>https://www.otelo.de/warenkorb.html?id=-1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeChecked</td>
    <td>id=mnp</td>
    <td>state</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>if</td>
    <td>${state}==false</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=mnp</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endIf</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello thx you for your help, but how can i check IF the checkbox is OFF then, turn it on, and if that checkbox was ON, just do nothing...

Comment: @mytrasher for [Conditional Statements refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498966/how-can-i-organize-if-else-selenium-ide)

Comment: @mytrasher then you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Hello Everybody,

@Madhan your Advice helped me alot, 

but now again i am stuck

https://www.otelo.de/handytarife/einsteiger-tarife/smartphone-100/page/2.html

i am trying to use

xpath=//input[@data-name="Internet-Flat 750"]

 to identify the options but it doesnt work , do you know what am i doing wrong?


THX U

Comment: Create it as a new question